# How to print and edit a specific element in an array list based on user's input/choice?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, arraylist

I've created a prototype in my code that allows the user to add, edit, and/or print their input. I have finalized options 1 (add employee),4 (print all employees) & 5 (exit). I'm stuck with options 2 (edit employee) and 3 (print employee) any advice or help would be incredible (new programmer)!

```
void loadMenu()
{
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("\nMAIN MENU\n");
        printf("1.Add Employee\n");
        printf("2.Edit Employee\n");
        printf("3.Print Employee\n");
        printf("4.Print ALL employees\n");
        printf("5.Exit\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1: printf("**Enter -1 for MAIN MENU** \n\n");
                NameInput();
                break;
        case 2: printf("Choose employee: \n");
                for (int i = 0; i < Times; i++)
                {
                 printf("%d. %s \n", i + 1, emps[i].emps.name);
                }

                scanf_s("%d", &choice);

        case 3: printf("Choose employee: \n\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < Times; i++)
                {
                 printf("%d. %s \n", i + 1, emps[i].emps.name);
                }
                scanf_s("%d", &choice);

        case 4: PayInput();
                break;
        case 5: printf("Quitting program!");
                exit(0);
                break;

       default: printf("Invalid choice tray again \n\n");
                break;
        }
    } while (choice != 5);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly you stuck? For the option `2`, just check whether the user input is in range, if it is not then throw error and if it is in range then edit that element of `emp` array using `emp[i]...`. For option `3`, follow the same and instead of edit, print that particular element of array `emp`.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a hint. You need to add your users in an array so you can compare within the for loop the user's selection. I'm going to write this on pseudocode to give you an idea:

```
 // Users array so you can have ["John, Paul, Ringo"]
 const char *users_list[100];
 users_list[0] = "John";
 users_list[1] = "Paul";
 users_list[2] = "Ringo";

 // Input's user
 selectedEmployee = "your user input"

 // The total elements inside of your array.
 int all_users = sizeof(users_list) / sizeof(users_list[0]);

 for (int i = 0; i < all_users; i++)
     {
         if(employee[i] == selectedEmployee){
             // If the users wrote "paul" is going to print paul user". 
             print selectedEmployee
          }
     }
```

This is just pseudocode, hopefully, this can help you to solve your problem. Remember, don't give up, no matter how hard it looks. Don't frustrate. Programming is complicated at the beginning.